# FFMpeg : Converting a video file to a gif with multiple images from video

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, ffmpeg

I am working on a project in which the user can upload videos. Is there any way with FFmpeg I can take some images from the video and create a GIF out of it?

As the project is in Java, I have a way to get an image from a video, but to create a GIF requires multiple images, and it's proving costly.

The server is running a Debian X64 system, so if FFMpeg is not suitable, I am open to other tools on Linux which can do this efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do scene extracting from videos using `vlc` for linux. If you don't have it, use

```
apt-get install vlc
```

to install it. Once installed, you can use a variance of the following command line to extract frame(s) out of your video. The default image format is `png` and it is good for my purpose. If you insist on `gif` images, I suggest installing `imagemagick` for image format conversions. Here is the command that extracts the frames:

```
cvlc ${videofile} \
         --video-filter=scene \
         --vout=dummy \
         --start-time=${start-sec} --stop-time=${end-sec} \
         --scene-ratio=1 --scene-prefix=${prefix} \
         --scene-path=${MyStorePath} \
         vlc://quit
```

where

> `videofile` is an mp4 format video. Other formats might be possible but
>   didn't test
>
> `start-sec` is where you want your frame grab starts from, in seconds from the beginning
>
> `end-sec` is where you want your frame grab ends, in seconds from the beginning. Must be greater than `start-sec`
>
> `prefix` is the prefix of the file names for captured images.
>
> `MyStorePath` is the path where you want to store captured images.

And this command helps you figure out the video length:

```
ffmpeg -i ${vidfile} 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

output is in `HH:MM:SS.xx` format. to convert this into video length in seconds, I use

```
l=$(ffmpeg -i ${vidfile} 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//)
h=$(echo $l|cut -d: -f1)
m=$(echo $l|cut -d: -f2)
s=$(echo $l|cut -d: -f3|cut -d"." -f1)
(( hh=$h*3600 ))
(( mm=$m*60 ))
(( LengthSeconds=$hh+$mm+$s ))
```

at this point you can manipulate the `LengthSeconds` variable to automatically determine start and end times. Unfortunately, for my `vlc` command to work, you **have to** specify a time slice to extract frames from.

Comment: Thank you, there is no desktop environment, I would have to go for headless VLC or whatever similar VLC has. Will your script work with that? Thank you.

Comment: This command does not require a desktop environment, if, by desktop env. you are referring to likes of gnome, KDE, xfce etc. It runs from the command line or you can put it in cron or any other job scheduler to run as desired

Comment: Thank you. I will try on Monday and will get back to you. :-)

Comment: Hi, SOrry for the late reply. Your code is working perfectly on my system. I just wanted to know if it's possible to automatically get the video seconds from the video file. I only require maybe 4-5 images from the video to make a GIF. Some videos can be short, so if VLC can get me the images without mentioning the seconds, it would be really awesome. Any ideas about that. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Please see the updates in my answer, for your latest question.

Comment: @MelBurslan you can get the duration in a much easier-to-parse format using ffprobe, which you should already have if you have ffmpeg. `ffprobe -show_format file.mp4 | grep -f 'duration=' | cut -d= -f2` should do it. It even gives the duration in seconds by default, so you don't have to bother converting.

Comment: @evilsoup your command also gives the output in HH:MM.SS.xx format. Also there is no `=` sign after the keyword `Duration`, but a `:`, as well as first letter of the keyword is UPPER case. Maybe you meant some other combination of command line switches but I am unable to get the length of video in seconds, using your command directly.

Comment: OK, I just downloaded the latest version to my Windows computer to test & it still outputs key=value pairs by default (& gives the duration in seconds). I think you might be looking at the big preamble that pops up whenever the program's run (which goes to STDERR), rather than the actual output (which goes to STDOUT) -- try just using `ffprobe -show_format file.mp4` and you might see what I mean. The juicy stuff will be underneath the preamble, and starts with `[FORMAT]`.

Comment: aah.. windows... I am on Linux OS here, CentOS 6 to be precise. And my version is close to the latest as I installed it from the original source like 2-3 months ago